# GSM Modem GPRS Data Send Delays

Tags: embedded, gsm, at-command, gprs

I'm trying to make a TCP connection between a server(in this case, my PC) and my telit gl865-dual modem.

I am connecting the modem via serial port(ftdi adaptor) and send or recieve data and commands directly my computer.

The connection can be established and data transmission can be done both ways. But when the modem sends data, there is a delay at least 3-5 seconds, the answer of server can be seen on module in miliseconds.

The commands I use(>> indicates the respond from module):

```
ad#sd = 1, 0, 4444, "myserversip"
>> CONNECT
```

Is there a way to arrange send time like server's?

Thanks.

Comment: What is taking the time?  TCP connect/disconnect is slow on a wireline, on a wireless stack it's very slow.  Are you connecting/disconnecting for each protocol exchange?

Comment: @MartinJames when the connection is established, I dont reconnect it every time. After "CONNECT" respond is came, I send the data like "asdf" in every 5 seconds but I can see them in my server in 8-10 seconds. The server's respond came instantly

Answer (score 0):

This must be due to slow network.

Check your network speed, if good then you have to see your server side code, why it's delaying.